# How can I view the config for a git branch?

Tags: git, configuration, branch

Is there a way I can check what branch a given local branch is tracking, and if it is setup to rebase automatically? These two are the main configuration options that I would like to check. I tried looking in my .git/config, but there's nothing in there about my local branch.

Answer (score 0):

you can see the output of

```
git remote show origin
```